# jiffies.h unknown

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm using a Linux 2.6.36 on a embedded system. I try to program something with semaphores. For this I need a function from the `jiffies.h` library. So good so far. When I include the Lib

either this way

```
#include <jiffies.h>
```

or this way

```
#include <linux/jiffies.h>
```

works.

But the strange thing is if I go to open declaration (eclipse comand) it opens an new editor window with the library. Does anyone have a clue what to do?

Comment: I know the problem ( i think :), the c-Code from the function in this header is not compiled yet. So but there the next problem appears: there is no jiffies.c, that means the functions are in other c files. How can I find out which one I have to compile?

Comment: Are you writing a kernel module, as in a device driver or something similar?  If so, then the functions in jiffies.h are already provided by the kernel, and I'd suspect a problem in how you're trying to compile your module.

Comment: @Peter I'm writing ( try to ) device driver. Your right there is a bug in the compiler process. I need to check the include path and so on. Where can I find the standard include path?

Comment: I found them. In the makefile.THat is the content: `LINUXINCLUDE    := -I$(srctree)/arch/$(hdr-arch)/include -Iinclude \
                   $(if $(KBUILD_SRC), -I$(srctree)/include) \
                   -include include/generated/autoconf.h`  The jiffies.h is in the include/linux/ path. so it should work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not building your module correctly.  A kernel module Makefile is extremely simple, and should look something like this, in its entirety:

```
obj-m := mymodule.o

mymodule.ko: mymodule.c mymodule.h
    $(MAKE) -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
```

The kernel build system will do the rest.  For more details, see the chapter on building modules at http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/

Editing:

Now it appears maybe you aren't trying to write a kernel module after all.  In that case, you don't want any include files that are part of the kernel source.  jiffies.h is not a userland include; it is a part of the kernel, used in writing parts of the kernel.  For userland semaphores, try POSIX semaphores.  Start with `man sem_overview`, and/or Google "POSIX semaphore".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At first I don't want to create a kernel module. Just a normal program. Than I think the issue is that I use a cross compiler ( power-pc-gcc)

Comment: Which one is it??? To my first question above, you said "Yes, I write device driver".  Now you say "No, I'm not writing a device driver".

Comment: Sry this one. I try first two write a algorithm as a normal program and later the driver.

Answer (score 0):

One mystery is solved: Eclipse store all file names in a project in a kind of list and when I click on `show declaration` it search in the list for that name and display the file. So it doesn't say anything about the compiler and the linker if this work. If that is not true please correct me.